# CDN from Azure not using HTTP2

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, http2, azure-cdn

I'm using Azure Storage Blobs and have Azure CDN in front of it serving static images and videos. I have been trying to get my website to use HTTP2 for a while now, but have run into issues with how Azure containerizes .NET Core applications on Linux machines. So, the website (using Kestrel), is only serving files over http/1.1 even if they're local files.

I thought that I could "offload" somethings by moving them to a storage blob container, then using Azure CDN. This article suggests that it should be available: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-http2

Is there something else I need to configure within my CDN profile or the Storage account to enable http/2? Or is it because my server is serving it as http/1.1?

Thanks,
AJ

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, I found a thread on Stack Overflow (sorry, on mobile and it's a pain to copy/paste links) about how some anti-virus softwares intercept requests to do SSL checking. Anyway, I use Bitdefender and when I went to Protection > Online Threat Prevention and disabled "Encrypted web scan" and then reloaded my domain, sure enough all traffic poured in over http2. I'm not sure why Bitdefender treated Akamai differently, but at least we know why now!